# Find three rational numbers $a,b,c$ s.t. $b^2-a^2=c^2-b^2=5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A rational numbers cannot have irrational as$\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, \, \sqrt[n]{\frac xy}$, but the two equalities give: $b^2=\frac{(a^2+c^2)}{2} \implies b = \sqrt[2]{\frac {(a^2+c^2)}{2}}$.
To avoid this, need $4\mid a$, & $a=c$; so that if $\exists t=a/2, \, b = \sqrt[2]{\frac {(a^2+c^2)}{2}} => 2t$.

As an example, $a=c=8, t=4, b=8$.

I am giving an idea for a particular case only, & am unable to pursue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Algebraic approach.**

First, note that $$a^2+c^2=2b^2,$$ and if denote
$$p=\dfrac{a}{b}, \quad q=\dfrac{c}{b}, \tag{1}$$
then we will search rational points on the circle
$$p^2+q^2=2.\tag{2}$$

According to the article [Keith Conrad "Arithmetic progressions of three squares"](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2007/3squarearithprog.pdf),
each rational solution of eq. $(2)$ (by exception of $(p,q)=(1,-1)$) can be written in the parametric form
$$
p = \dfrac{m^2-2m-1}{m^2+1}, \qquad q=\dfrac{-m^2-2m+1}{m^2+1},\\
\left( m = \dfrac{q-1}{p-1}\right),\tag{3}
$$
where $m$ is rational parameter (positive or negative); 
and vice versa (for each rational $m$ pair $(p,q)$ will have rational coordinates).

If we require distance (step) $n=5$ between numbers $a^2,b^2,c^2$ in algebraic progression, then (according to Corollary $3.3$ of the article above) each rational solution of equation $$b^2-a^2=c^2-b^2=n\tag{4}$$ can be written in the form
$$
a=\dfrac{x^2-2nx-n^2}{2y}, \quad b=\dfrac{x^2+n^2}{2y}, \quad c=\dfrac{x^2+2nx-n^2}{2y},
\\
\left(\; x=\dfrac{n(c-b)}{a-b}, \qquad y=\dfrac{n^2(2b-a-c)}{(a-b)^2} \right),
\tag{5}
$$
where $(x,y)$ is rational point on the [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)
$$
y^2=x^3-nx;\tag{6}
$$
and vice versa (each rational point of the EC $(6)$ detemines rational solution of eq. $(4)$).

---

As was discussed before, one simple positive rational solution is $$(a,b,c) = \left(\dfrac{31}{12}, \dfrac{41}{12}, \dfrac{49}{12}\right);$$

in fact, it means that there are $8$ rational solutions:
$$(a,b,c)=\left(\pm\dfrac{31}{12}, \pm\dfrac{41}{12}, \pm\dfrac{49}{12}\right),$$
for which (see $(5), (6)$) we have the set of $8$ rational points on the EC $(6)$:
$$
(x,y) = \left(-4,\pm 6\right), \\ (x,y) = \left( 45, \pm 300\right), \\
(x,y) = \left(-\frac{5}{9},\pm \frac{100}{27}\right), \\ 
(x,y) = \left( \frac{25}{4}, \pm \frac{75}{8}\right).
$$

Applying the beauty of [the group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) of EC, we can derive other rational points from existing ones.

**Example:**

if we'll take starting point $P_1=(-4,6)$, then 
denote point $P_2$ as $P_2 = P_1+P_1$ 
(note that we 'add' two points not coordinate-wise, but according to [the group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) of EC): 
$\; P_2 =  \left( \frac{1681}{144} , -\frac{62279}{1728} \right)$,
which leads to the solution 
$$(a,b,c) = \left(\frac{113279}{1494696}, - \frac{3344161}{1494696}, \frac{4728001}{1494696}\right);$$
then let's denote $P_3$ as $P_3 = P_1+P_2$:
$\; P_3 = \left(-\frac{2439844}{5094049} , \frac{39601568754}{11497268593} \right)$,
which leads to the solution
$$(a,b,c) = \left(
-\frac{518493692732129}{178761481355556}, 
 \frac{654686219104361}{178761481355556}, 
 \frac{767067390499249}{178761481355556} \right). $$

---

This way, if focus on positive solutions $(a,b,c)$ of eq. $(4)$ in the form $(a,b,c)=\left(\frac{A}{D},\frac{B}{D},\frac{C}{D}\right)$, where $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{N}$, we can construct series of rational points (with increasing size of common denominator):

\begin{array}{|l|}
\hline
A=31; \\
B=41; \\
C=49; \\
D=12; \\
\hline
A=113279; \\
B=3344161; \\
C=4728001; \\
D=1494696; \\
\hline
A=518493692732129; \\
B=654686219104361; \\
C=767067390499249; \\
D=178761481355556; \\
\hline
A=249563579992463717493803519; \\
B=249850594047271558364480641; \\
C=250137278774864229623059201; \\
D=5354229862821602092291248; \\
\hline
A=115038188620995226180802686473825513089249; \\
B=160443526614433014168714029147613242401001; \\
C=195577262542844878506138849501555847171249; \\
D=50016678000996026579336936742637753055940; \\
\hline
A=21214405287844054428542609853501469645112322962237848990081;\\
B=209239116668342644167838867143329714389679018137228536721441; \\
C=295147361324101461665473218814630755582253386512598845803201; \\
D=93092380947563478644577555596900542802151091304399908363272; \\
\hline
\ldots
\end{array}

Answer (score 3):

The general solution of $b^2-a^2=5$ has
$$b=\frac12\left(t+\frac 5t\right)$$
for $t\in\Bbb Q^*$. Then
$$c^2=b^2+5=\frac{t^4+10t^2+25}{4t^2}+5=\frac{t^4+30t^2+25}{4t^2}.$$
The problem boils down to whether the genus-one curve
$$y^2=x^4+30x^2+25$$
has rational points.

Comment: Thanks, but am not clear about the general solution of $b^2-a^2$ being $b=\frac12\left(t+\frac 5t\right)$.

Comment: Let $t=b-a$. @jiten

Comment: $5=(b-a)(b+a)$ so $b+a=5/t$. @jiten

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the reason for choosing the value of parameter $t$. But, I am unable to understand the last line. Please tell me how to pursue the algebraic curve aspect.

Comment: Here $x=t$ and $y=2ct$. @jiten

Comment: I do not get better by your last comment, may be need read into algebraic curves?

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite these numbers with common denominator $D$:
$a=\dfrac{A}{D}$, $\;b=\dfrac{B}{D}$, $\;c=\dfrac{C}{D}$. Then we'll get diophantine equation (system of diophantine equations):
$$
B^2-A^2=C^2-B^2=5D^2.\tag{1}
$$
The smallest solution of $(1)$ is $(A,B,C,D)=(31,41,49,12)$.

So, example of such three rational numbers $a,b,c$ is: $$a=\dfrac{31}{12},\quad b=\dfrac{41}{12}, \quad c=\dfrac{49}{12}.$$

---

Short algorithm (to find $A,B,C,D$) description:

- for each $C$ (from some range) consider $B = 1,2,\ldots,C-1$;

  - if $2B^2-C^2$ is square number, then denote $A=\sqrt{2B^2-C^2}$;

    - if $\dfrac{B^2-A^2}{5}$ is square number, then denote $D=\sqrt{\frac{B^2-A^2}{5}}$ and output $(A,B,C,D)$.

Comment: Please give explicitly a way to generate the given set of $3$ numbers, as it seems like a calculation done, and not a method(way).

Comment: I hope that given the algorithmic nature of your answer, some example run would make it better to understand.

Comment: [python code](http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_M4Ub41omissmPmq.py), you can edit the code to look at more details.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thanks for the code, it will help me to understand the given answer, and to work on all such problems in future too. If you could please help me with the first answer, as the given concepts of algebraic curves are really difficult to find for a UG level by me till now (many attempts, in quite some time now- with the 'time' spanning in months).

Comment: I am not familiar with finding rational points.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Agreed, but if could help finding literature source(s) for UG level that lucidly covers such topics, then would serve equally. I feel my request is like one blind man asking another one, but I am exponentially more blind, as have no way to ask others except you.

Comment: It is for my reference to understand the python code better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489580/3693431

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I have been experimenting to get the results in a modified format. The current (not final at all, due to too many modifications needed to at least remove debugging print statements) is at: http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_XOUjuI50Gv_31.py. But, it is some thing striking/confusing to me that all the points are multiples of each other. It seems that the first one is a primitive root (i.e., the common $\gcd$ is $1$). Any reason for that?

Comment: @jiten: I really appreciate your interest to the question and to finding proper way to solve it; when I'll have more time, I'll describe algebraic approach which allows generate series of irreducible fraction triples $(a,b,c)$ which match the condition above; here is just $2$nd example: 
$$a=\dfrac{113279}{1494696}, \quad b=\dfrac{3344161}{1494696}, c=\dfrac{4728001}{1494696}.$$

Comment: @Oleg567 Thanks for your kind response. Would be anxiously waiting for your answer for 'proper' way to get multiple unique set of values of $A,B,C$. In the meantime, if could get the name, or a literature source for the method.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please note, and also for my reference: the latest (unclean) version is at : http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_lgXa0MjQBO_29.py

Comment: Of course integer multiple of them is going to be another solution, since they will be normalized by $D$. What is interesting is obtaining another nontrivial rational solution systematically of which Oleg567 should be able to help you better.